# Ts-jest giving error when importing json file in my Nodejs App

Tags: typescript, ts-jest

I have a simple ExpressJS App which imports a json file as
`import config from './config.json' assert {type: json}`

I was forced to write the assert statement as nodejs complained and also had to make module as exnext in tsconfig.json

Doing all this made a successful compilation and I was able to run the app successfully with expected results.

However when I tried unit testing with jest and ts-jest I got the same error that I cannot use assert statement without making module as esnext in tsconfig.json which I have already done.

I am able to compile and run the app but not unit test it.
Please let me know what additional configuration I could try to make this work.